# spring boot + jpa + jersey could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jersey

I am trying to query a database via a rest api using `jersey` and `spring boot jpa` with `hibernate`.

My controller method:

```
public SomeValue doSomething(String param) {

    MyEntity entity = myService.queryDB(param);
    return conv.convertEntity(entity);
}
```

My service:

```
@Transactional
public MyEntity queryDB(String param) {
    return myRepo.findOne(param);
}
```

The entity:

```
@Entity
MyEntity {

@Id
@NotNull
private String Id;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="foreignKey", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<SomeOtherEntity> someOtherEntity;

}
```

I even explicitly set the property in the application.yml:

```
open-in-view: true
```

I get the following exception:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: entitites.MyEntity.someOtherEntity, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

During debugging I can see that the `preHandle` method of Spring's `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` is called *after* I make the call to the repository. Shouldn't it be called before?

What could be causing this exception / behaviour. What is wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 0):

It's the lazy mode that cause this exception try to edited your code and use this instead:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="foreignKey", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<SomeOtherEntity> someOtherEntity;
```